# search through a multi dimentional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to search through a multi dimentional array and find all the values of the 3rd value by looking for a word in the 1st element

```
array

car,blue,34

bus,yellow,55

car,green,88

truck,blue,55

bus,yellow,44
```

So I want to het all the numbers  that are a car....so 34,88

Comment: can you show how you are filling the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i][0] == "car") numbers.push(arr[i][2]);
}
```

Comment: I believe you mean to push index `2`.

Answer (score 0):

if your 'arrays' look like this:

```
 stuff = {}
 stuff['car'] = {};
 stuff['car']['blue'] = 34;
 stuff['car']['red'] = 100;
 stuff['bus'] = {};
 stuff['bus']['yellow'] = 99;
```

then you want to do something like this:

```
 searchfor = 'car';
 results= [];
 for(var i in stuff) {
   if (i==searchfor) {
      for(var ii in stuff[i]) {
          results[] = stuff[i][ii];
      }
   }
 }
return results;
```

results will look like this

```
[34,100]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

Give an array that look like this:

```
var items = [
    ['car','blue',34],
    ['bus','yellow',55],
    ['car','green',88],
    ['truck','blue',55],
    ['bus','yellow',44]
    ];
```

You would first filter the array based on the type (the value of position 0) then map those results on to a new array:

```
function getAttributes(type, pos) {
    return items.filter(function(val) {
        return val[0] === type;
    }).map(function(val) {
        return val[pos];
    });
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
alert(getAttributes('car', 2));
```

Results:

```
[34,88]
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9na8nh37/)

Or you could use a for loop to do the same:

```
function getAttributes(type, pos) {
    var retVal = [];
    var len    = items.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if(items[i][0] === type) {
            retVal.push(items[i][pos]);
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9na8nh37/1/)